# How to loop through all directories and use folders as names?

Tags: linux, unix

I am looking for a way to loop through all the directories in my folder and get the first name of the folder. Folders are named name-something-something. I want name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for d in *; do (a="$(echo $d| cut -d - -f1)" && echo $a); done
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Comment: gotta love clean one liners!